# Invoke a CRUD controller that sits in a module

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I have a Play 1.2.x app that uses the CRUD module. I am also working on a module for this app that also has to use the CRUD module So, I added a model and a CRUD controller in the modules, added the CRUD module as a dependency, and also added my custom module in the global routes file:

```
*       /                   module:mymodule
*      /admin              module:crud
```

yet, no matter what I do, I cannot see an entry for that CRUD controller, the way normally CRUd controllers work. I see all the CRUD functionality from the main the main, but nothing from the custom module.

I suspect it might be either a routing issue (something I need to add to the routes file of the module), or the CRUD plugin simply does not support this kind of functionality.

Could anyone help me here? Thanks

Comment: Did you add `module:crud` in the 'mymodule' routes file as well?

Comment: Also, in these situations it usually helps to 'expand' the routes file, by going to a nonexisting page in DEV mode, which gives you a list of all routes Play sees (or copying in the routes files of the modules). This makes it easier to spot problems with routing priority and missing routes.

Answer (score 0):

Step one, remove route for your module, only keep route for module:crud, just like this:

```
*      /admin              module:crud
```

Step two, create your controller, for example:

```
@CRUD.For(MyModel.class)
public class MyController extends CRUD {
    // Some your codes
}
```

Step three, start your project, and navigate to `/admin/mycontroller`.

Hope this help.